# Java static code analysis

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

I am looking for eclipse/netbeans plugin or a tool, which analysis java project, and give us a report of unused imports, unused variables, unused methods, **violating custom naming conventions**, etc..

Comment: Have you tried searching on stackoverflow?

Comment: @Surendhar For eclipse please have findbug pluging with you. Its really useful.

Comment: Have a look a similar question is asked here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321282/which-is-the-best-tool-for-finding-bugs-in-the-java-code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse provides it as `Markers`. It will provide all your cases except `violating custom naming conventions`.

[image]

Comment: Will it do naming convention analysis?

Answer (score 3):

[Findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) works well as Eclipse plugin, and is easily customizable.

If you're looking for something bigger, or you work in a continous integration environment, I'd go for [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/).

Comment: We use findbugs with TeamCity -- it does integrate with CB environments.

Answer (score 2):

FindBugs is probably one of the most prominent ones and well worth a try.

For naming conventions etc, I'd suggest you have a look at CheckStyle.

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans 7.2 has a new Inspect feature: goto Source|Inspect from the menu. It certainly has most of the tests for mentioned in your question.

Comment: agreed! In combination with findbugs plugin its very usefull and capable of doing many common modification (like fixing imports) all over a project with some clicks.

Answer (score 2):

... in addition look at [sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/). It's been quiet the eye opener when I first discovered it.

Answer (score 2):

For the little things like naming conventions and imports, I agree with the other answers that PMD is a pretty good choice.

[shameless plug] This may be overkill, but there's a tool called "Codefacts" that the company that I work at developed, which will analyze your code from a git or svn repository. It runs metrics and stuff to assess code quality. It might fit into your "etc.."

I can't recall all of the metrics it uses, but some of them are things like comment/code ratio, documentation coverage, checking if a lot of your methods/classes are too long, and a bunch more. 
[Codefacts can be downloaded here](http://www.avi.com/codefacts/)
[/shameless plug]

Answer (score 1):

I use combination of three tools which supplement each other: PMD, Checkstyle and FindBugs.

Comment: Either of this do, naming convention analysis?

Answer (score 0):

Try Checkstyle (my preference) or PMD.